# Java JFrame not getting focus when called from a class different than main

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Java JFrame not getting focus when opened from a different method than main

I am doing an Arkanoid game, before the game starts it has some menus for loggin, customization, select level... So when I say the game I will be refering only to the actual game and not the menus.

If I run `App.main(String[] args)` and that method calls the method which creates the game and starts running, it will work. However if the method contained in `App.main(String[] args)` calls for example a method to launch the main menu, the select menu, customization menu... and from one of those menus I lauch the method that creates the game, it would lauch but not give it focus.

To ilustrate you, this would launch the game with no problem:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Arkanoid().getArkanoid(lvl).run();
    }
}
```

This would load the game and the ball would move but the paddle used to hit the ball won't and the frame coul not be closed eventhough having `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SelectLevelWindow();
    }
}

public class SelectLevelWindow(){
   
    ...

    private JButton getBtnStart(){

    //button creation

    @Override
    btnStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 frame.dispose();
                 Arkanoid().getArkanoid(lvl).run();
                 }
    });
```

If I launch one menu from another, the second menu works perfectly but this doesn't happend for the game. Here is the code of the game:

```
public class Arkanoid extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    // Housekeeping
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Game variables
    private Game game;
    private Paddle paddle = new Paddle(Config.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50);
    private Ball ball = new Ball(Config.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    private Ball ball2 = null;
    private List<Brick> bricks = new ArrayList<Brick>();
    private ScoreBoard scoreboard = new ScoreBoard();

    private int numBalls = 1;
    private static Arkanoid mArkanoid; 

    private double lastFt;
    private double currentSlice;
    
    private int level;

    
    public static Arkanoid getArkanoid(int lvl) {
        if (mArkanoid == null) mArkanoid = new Arkanoid(lvl);
        return mArkanoid;
    }
    
    
    public Arkanoid(int lvl) {
        
        game = new Game ();
        level = lvl;
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setUndecorated(false);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(Config.SCREEN_WIDTH, Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        this.setTitle("Arkanoid");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bricks = Game.initializeBricks(bricks, nivel);
    }
        

    public void run() {
        
        this.prepareGame();

        BufferStrategy bf = this.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = bf.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        
        game.setRunning(true);

        while (game.isRunning()) {
            long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (!scoreboard.gameOver && !scoreboard.win) {
                //logger.info("Playing");
                game.setTryAgain(false);
                update();
                drawScene(ball, bricks, scoreboard);

                // to simulate low FPS
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                    //logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }

            } else {
                if (game.isTryAgain()) {
                    //logger.info("Trying again");
                    game.setTryAgain(false);
                    bricks = Game.initializeBricks(bricks, nivel);
                    scoreboard.lives = Config.PLAYER_LIVES;
                    scoreboard.score = 0;
                    scoreboard.win = false;
                    scoreboard.gameOver = false;
                    scoreboard.updateScoreboard();
                    ball.x = Config.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                    ball.y = Config.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
                    paddle.x = Config.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                }
            }

            long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double elapsedTime = time2 - time1;

            lastFt = elapsedTime;

            double seconds = elapsedTime / 1000.0;
            if (seconds > 0.0) {
                double fps = 1.0 / seconds;
                //logger.info("FPS: " + fps);
            }

        }

        this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));

    }

    private void update() {

        currentSlice += lastFt;

        for (; currentSlice >= Config.FT_SLICE; currentSlice -= Config.FT_SLICE) {

            ball.update(scoreboard, paddle, nivel);
            paddle.update();

            Game.testCollision(paddle, ball, nivel);
            if (ball2 != null) Game.testCollision(paddle, ball2, nivel);


            Iterator<Brick> it = bricks.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Brick brick = it.next();
                Game.testCollision(brick, ball, scoreboard, nivel);
                if (ball2 != null )Game.testCollision(brick, ball2, scoreboard, nivel);

                if (brick.destroyed) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawScene(Ball ball, List<Brick> bricks, ScoreBoard scoreboard) {

        BufferStrategy bf = this.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = null;

        try {

            g = bf.getDrawGraphics();

            g.setColor(Config.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            ball.draw(g);
            paddle.draw(g);
            for (Brick brick : bricks) {
                brick.draw(g);
            }
            scoreboard.draw(g);

        } finally {
            g.dispose();
        }

        bf.show();

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            game.setRunning(false);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            game.setTryAgain(true);
        }
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            paddle.moveLeft();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            paddle.moveRight();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            paddle.stopMove();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}
```

If you need any other method or class just ask. Here is the link for the gitHub repositorie https://github.com/Boscoaran/ADSI-21-22-Arkanoid.git **develop branch** I think the problem is loosing the focus somewhere but I have tried requesting the focus in different parts and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The question is translated to spanish [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510521/java-jframe-controles-del-teclado-y-focus-no-funcionan)

Comment: 1) When you start in the main() no component has focus so focus will be placed on the frame when it is made visible. When you click on the button, the button has focus. If you wan the frame to have focus made you need to add a `requestFocusInWindow(...)` statement to give a component focus. 2) code from the main() does NOT execute on the EDT. All Swing components should be created/modified on the EDT. When you click the button the code code DOES execute on the EDT. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: 3) Don't use a MouseListener on buttons. Instead you should be using an `ActionListener` to handle the clicking of the button 4) Don't use Thread.sleep. If you need animation use a Swing Timer. 5) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. 6) Not sure why you are using a BufferStrategy. Swing is double buffered by default. The above tutorial link also contains section on these concepts.

Comment: *"Here is the link for the gitHub repositories.."* Code at a link might change, or be removed. I will not visit them in any case. Uncompilable code snippets as seen above do not allow me to test the code and try out ideas to fix the problem. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].